# How to compute the Gromov-Hausdorff distance between spheres $S_n$ and $S_m$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, metric-spaces

Can we compute the Gromov-Hausdorff distance $d(\mathbb{S}_n,\mathbb{S}_m)$ for two different spheres $\mathbb{S}_n$ and $\mathbb{S}_m$, $m\neq n$? We consider the spheres with the metrics induced by the embedding
$\mathbb{S}_n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

For $n=2$, $m=3$, this is evaluating $$d(\mathbb{S}_2,\mathbb{S}_3)=\inf_{M,f,g}d_{M}(\mathbb{S}_2,\mathbb{S}_3)$$ where $M$ ranges over all possible metric spaces and $f:\mathbb{S}_2\to M$ and $g:\mathbb{S}_3\to M$ range over all possible distance-preserving embeddings. As an upper bound, $d(\mathbb{S}_2,\mathbb{S}_3)\leq \sqrt{2}$.

More generally for $0 \leq n \leq m$,
$$d(\mathbb{S}_n,\mathbb{S}_m)\leq d(point,S_n)+d(point,S_m)\leq 2$$
But I find it difficult to control the lower bound with the inf over all possible metric spaces $M$.

I conjecture that for all $0 \leq n \leq m$:
$$d(\mathbb{S}_n,\mathbb{S}_m)\geq \lambda_{m,n}\frac{m-n}{m}, \text{ where } \liminf_{m,n\to \infty}\lambda_{m,n}>0$$

I only know the Gromov-Hausdorff theory from Petersen's *Riemannian Geometry*, which does not give enough information to compute this distance. I will appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Did you see Druţu, Cornelia "Quasi-isometry invariants and asymptotic cones"? There are some examples of computing GH-distance in the paper.

Comment: Please check your question for typos.

Comment: @Mark Sapir,Appreciate for help!I am reading the article you point out,it seems this article mainly focus on investigating the Gromov-Hausdorff limit  space of a sequence of hyperbolic group equipped with modified G-H metric defined in 2.A with some special condition to ensure the limit space exists.and take a sequences corvarage to the limit space,the hyperbolic property and some other thing is stayed by the process of take limit.

Comment: @Mark Sapir,So it is natural for us to investigate the original space by some information from the limit space.there is a series of bi-product state in 3.B.but I do not see where the author exactly calculate some groom-hausdorff distance of two different space,may you point out it?appreciate again!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez,Corrected, thanks.

Comment: I fixed numerous typos. In particular, you should use spacing after each punctuation mark; capitals to begin sentences and names.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me to correct the mistakes! I will know how to write in a correct style.

Comment: Your conjecture would imply that the GH distance is unbounded. But it's clearly bounded, since the GH distance of any sphere to a point is equal to 2 (when the sphere is endowed with the restriction of Euclidean distance, as you seem to assume, or $\pi$ when endowed with geodesic distance) and hence the GH distance between any two spheres is $\le 4$.

Comment: You are right,In fact if we use the canonical embed, then we can get $d_{G-H}(S_n,S_m)\leq 2$ by another equivalent definition of GH distance.I confuse the geometry picture of the pairs $T_n,S_n$ with the pairs $S_n,S_m$,for $S_n,S_m$ case,I thick the seems correct conjecture will be $d_{G-H}(S_n,S_m)\sim \frac{m-n}{m},0\leq n\leq m,m,n\to \infty$.

Comment: Clearly from standard embeddings we get $d_{GH}(S_n,S_m)\le\sqrt{2}$ for all $n,m\ge 0$. Would it be reasonable to simply conjecture that it's an equality whenever $n\neq m$?

Comment: Yeah, you are right,$d_{G-H}(S_n,S_m)\leq \sqrt{2}$ for all $n,m\geq 0$.I find the interesting problem when I want to find a toy model of a kind of problem,roughly speaking is to investigate a map $f:X\to Y$ from low-dimensions space $X$ to high-dimension space $Y$ stay some affine structure of the low-dimension space $X$. This structure could have some control by the distance function on the low-dimension space, so if we can get some control on the variation of the Energy of distance function, this will share some line on the original problem I consider.

Comment: And we know for the case $S_n,S_m$, if $n,m$ is very near to each other,then the two space should be more near, and there is a canonical embed $S_0\subset S_1 \subset S_2 ....\subset S_n \subset ...$. So it is natural to conjecture if $m,n$ is very near then the distance $d_{G-H}(S_n,S_m)$ is very small. .

Comment: I have a very rough strategy to prove the conjecture, that is inspired by the Nash embedding theorem. I just mean if we consider the problem in this frame $d_{G-H}(S_n,S_m)=\inf_{M,g,f}(d_M(f(S_n),g(S_m)))$ then the difficult is the deformation space of $M,g,f$ is too large. so the first step is to establish a regular lemma, to prove the function $d_M(f(S_n),g(S_m))$ is continues under the small perbutation of $M$ and reduced to the situation of space $M,g,f$ with very nice regularity.

Comment: The second part is to embed $M $ to a big euclid space $R^N$ as subspace, and the embedding stay the length of geodesic.locally this is determine by a group of pde:$u_i(x)u_j(x)=g_{ij}(x)$,at least in the cut locus.but there should be some critical point,and I do not know how to deal with them.the third,i.e. the last step is to calculate $d_{G-H}(S_n,S_m)$ in the very some deformation space $M,f,g$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67804/discussion-between-hu-xiyu-and-ycor).

Comment: Btw $d_{GH}(\mathbb{S}^0,\mathbb{S}^n)=1$ for all $n\ge 1$. It's a nice exercise (and so far the only case I could compute).

Comment: And in addition there is the obvious remark (I didn't first notice) that $d(S_n,S_m)\le 1$ for all $n,m$ (form a metric space $S_n\sqcup S_m$ with the given distance on each component and points in different components being at distance 1. This works for any two metric spaces of diameter $\le 2$. So my previous comment should rather ask whether $d_{GH}(S_n,S_m)=1$ for all $n\neq m$.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I can transform the problem into a problem in graph theory and I think this point of view can basically solve the problem. I will type my idea later.

Comment: I can show that $d_{GH}(S^1,S^n)>s=\sqrt{2}/4=0.35\dots$ but it's already a bit complicated. The idea is that if $S^n$ is $s$-close to $S^1$ somewhere, then, use a large circle $C$ in $S^n$, and show $(*)$ that every point of $S^1$ is at distance $<3\sqrt{2}/4$ of a point in $C$. Indeed, choose a point $p$ in $S^n$ at distance $\sqrt{2}$ to $C$, and choose $x\in S^1$ at distance $<\sqrt{2}/4$ to $p$. By $(*)$, $x$ is at distance $<\sqrt{2}/4$ to some point $q$ in $C$. Then $pq\le px+xq$ gives $\sqrt{2}<\sqrt{2}/4+3\sqrt{2}/4$, contradiction.

Comment: It remains to prove $(*)$, assuming that some $x\in C$ is at distance $\ge 3\sqrt{2}/4$ of $C$, so every point $p$ in $C$ is at distance $<\sqrt{2}/4$ to a point $f(p)$ in some "interval" of $S^1$ (the complement $J$ of the $\ge 3\sqrt{2}/4$-ball around $x$). This yields a natural orientation of pairs in $J$, and one can show that for $p\in C$, the orientation of the pair $(f(p),f(-p))$ is locally constant in $p$, which is a contradiction. (I omit details!)

Comment: I use some strange fibration to construct a special distance to show $d_{G-H}(S_n,S_m)$ is much less than 1,but there can not upload picture.I upload it in the chat room.

Comment: The first powerful tool is the $\delta$ separate cover set to approximation the original set.for $S^n$,let $A_{n,\delta}$ define as a set of $\delta$ separate cover of $S^n$.that is just mean:1.$\forall x\neq y\in A_{n,\delta}$,$d(x,y)>\delta$.2.$\forall z\in S^n,\exists x\in A_{n,\delta},d(x,z)<100^n\delta$.

Comment: It is easy to proof $d_{G-H}(S^n,A_{\delta,n})<2\delta$.so $\lim_{\delta\to 0^+} d_{G-H}(S^n,A_{\delta,n})=0$,so to calculate $d_{G-H}(s_n,s_m)$,it is suffice to calculate $\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}d_{G-H}(A_{n,\delta},A_{m,\delta})$.in particular,we need only take care of a very small scale $\delta$ then $|d_{G-H}(S_n,S_m)-d_{G-H}(A_{n,\delta},A_{m,\delta})|<4\delta$.

Comment: Now we just need to look at $d_{G-H}(A_{n,\delta},A_{m,\delta})$.this behavior is easy to control.in fact this is two complete graph $G_{S_n},G_{S_m}$ with metric induce by the original metric in $S_n,S_m$.we have $|G_{S_n}|\sim \delta^{-n}$,$|G_{S_m}| \sim \delta^{-m}$.assume $m>n$ so if we consider the map between $G_{S_n},G_{S_m}$ define as $f_{n,m}(a)=b$ iff $d_M(a,b)=inf_{c\in G_{S_n}}d_M(a,c)$.so this is almost a 1 to $\delta^{n-m}$ map.

Comment: Now this thing become very interesting,in the "high dimension" space $A_{m,\delta}$ induced by $S_m$,there is $\delta^{-m}$ points,and they group in $\delta^{-n}$ group.the key point is there is some monotonic property,that just mean the situation will be worse if the points in groups distribution very uniformly,this will make the freedom low down and the distance $d_H(S_n,S_m)$ will be larger.so every group must concentrate at a very small area to make the Gromov-Hausdorff distance to arrive minimum.

Comment: @Huxiyu: See Example on page 3.

Comment: the natural embed $S_n$ into $S_m$ as a nearly fibration structure is just make the groups to be longitudes.this is far away from the best choice because every longitudes intersection each other at the poles. Obviously there is a better choice, choose some groups near the poles use the longitude firbration and when near the equatorial use the latitude firbration.this will make $d_{H}(S_n,S_m)$ much smaller.

Comment: but I still do not know how to calculate $d_{G-H}(S_n,S_m)$ exactly...although now we have nontrivial lower bound and upper bound...

Comment: @Mark Sapir, Appreciate! This is a good example to calculate the Gromov-Hausdorff metric,but in this situation is too special, I think the mainly thing the author use is the local isometry property. In fact a segment is isometry to a half circle, And then just consider the line and ball as covering space of a segment or half circle. Then we only need to charge the situation near the endpoint of the segment or half circle.

Answer (score 9):

Hu Xiyu. Even though yours is a question from four years ago, I want to bring to your attention my recent paper “Gromov-Hausdorff distance between spheres”( https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.00611 ) coauthored with Facundo Memoli and Zane Smith, since it is very closely related to your question.

In this paper, we compute/bound the Gromov-Hausdorff distance between two spheres with different dimension (each with geodesic metric). We use topological methods in order to obtain lower bounds: more precisely, we resort to a certain version of Borsuk-Ulam Theorem for discontinous functions. On the other hand, we design specialized optimal correspondences in order to estimate upper bounds. In particular, we were able to compute precise value of the Gromov Hausdorff distance for $\mathbb{S}^1$ vs $\mathbb{S}^2$, $\mathbb{S}^1$ vs $\mathbb{S}^3$, and $\mathbb{S}^2$ vs $\mathbb{S}^3$.

Finally, the last section of the paper deals with the case of spheres with Euclidean metric. Even though we could not give a full answer, I believe you will be able to find some useful observations there.